# Ajax поиск для сайта Wordpress

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

Задача: настроить поиск по страницам определенной категории сайта `Wordpress`. **Требования:**

1. Поиск через `Ajax`
2. Вывод информации только при 100% соответствии
   названию страницы
3. Поиск доступен для неавторизованных на сайте пользователей

Посоветуйте какой плагин мог бы справится с этой задачей? Пытался реализовать данную задачу при помощи [Ajax Search Pro](http://demo.wp-dreams.com/), но поиск работает только для авторизованных на сайте пользователей.

Comment: Возьми настройки [отсюда](http://wp-dreams.com/demo/ajax-search-pro-admin/wp-admin/admin.php?page=ajax-search-pro%2Fbackend%2Findex_table.php)- возможно `Ajax Search Pro ` заработает

Comment: а если допилить вручную, Ajax Search Pro, чтобы он работал и для не авторизованных пользователей ?  Единственное незабыть, неавторизованными могут быть роботы или дети которые могут "повесить" Ваш сайт !

Comment: Готовых плагинов на абсолютно все случаи жизни нет. Видимо, нужно либо дорабатывать штатный поиск, либо наиболее подходящий плагин.

Answer (score 0):

Вот хороший плагин который можно будет допилить потом со временем и без авторизации можно использовать https://github.com/crowdfavorite-mirrors/wp-daves-wordpress-live-search проверял на последних версия WP все работало отлично